# Issue with httpd. unable to view any files on folder

Tags: http, mime-types, mime, permission-denied, mimemagic

I have a created file serving tool using http. it was working without any issue. I did recently upgraded to httpd services. post that not able view/open any files.

my http.conf

```html
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf 
User apache
Group apache

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 +TLSv1.2 

SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression      off
SSLSessionTickets   off



SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/tool.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/tool.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/tool.crt
Servername 10.x.x.x
</VirtualHost>

ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot "/opt"

<Directory "/opt">

 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/tool">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>   
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
        MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

my error:

```html
[Mon Apr 25 22:42:04.696565 2022] [mime_magic:error] [pid 16538] (13)Permission denied: [client 10.x.x.x:53639] AH01513: mod_mime_magic: read failed: /opt/Backup/2022/Apr/25/device.config
```

not sure, how to fix this issue.

my finding,

1.when give permission 751 to files, i am able to see but unable to open it getting some error.

error

```html
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /tool/2022/Apr/25/device.config on this server.
```

2.when i create files extension with .txt able to see but able to open not able to see any content. getting below

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD
```

am not from dev background. need some help here.

Comment: Whatever is serving that content is unable to access it. It is unclear what you did to get to this point, though, so maybe [edit] the question and tell use what you changed exactly and what was "working" previously. Also, this might be more suited for another SE that has more to do with whatever HTTP service you are using.

Comment: Welcome. This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Good luck.